# Query for email existing is in database and not empty

Tags: django

I'm looking for single-line filter query if given email is already in database but allow for empty value.

forms.py

```
 def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        q = Email.objects.filter(email=email)
        if not email or q.count() == 0:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError('Podany email już widnieje w bazie')
```

models.py

```
class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write `validator` for it:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_email(value):
    q = Email.objects.filter(email=value)
    if not q.exists():
        return email
    raise ValidationError('Podany email już widnieje w bazie')
```

`forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, validators=[validate_email])
```

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, validators=[validate_email])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists()`

```
Email.objects.filter(email=email).exists()
```

Returns `True` is an instance was found.

Comment: I think you have not considered when a user gives an empty mail.

Comment: `if not Email.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError('Podany email już widnieje w bazie')` return raise when email is empty which is wrong